# Why do I get a stack overflow?

Tags: ocaml

I am making a simple program that sums all the numbers to n. I am curious why I get a stack overflow when I don't use parentheses on n-1 and I don't when I use them.

```
let rec summing n=
  if n=0
  then 0 
  else n+ summing n-1;; (*(n-1)*)
summing 5;;
```

Comment: It's parsing it as `(summing n) - 1` rather than `summing (n - 1)`. So it's not well-founded recursion. You can verify this by adding some kind of print statement at the top of your function.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that without the parentheses the order of operations for this:

```
n+ summing n-1
```

Is implied as this:

```
(n) + (summing n) - (1)
```

Which means the same value of `n` is always recursively passed until the stack overflows.  Explicitly using the parentheses allows you to pass `n - 1` recursively.

Comment: Even if we write it as `let rec summing n = if n = 0 then 0 else n + summing (n -1)` it's possible that for very large values of `n`, stack could be san issue. Politely suggest @tacocat looks into tail-recursion and accumulators.